# Error in appcompat version during gradle

Tags: android

[image]

I am getting below error

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
>   for line 27, I am novice in android & trying to use google play service and map
>   I have updated manifest file with  but after I move to build.gradle it is showing this error

Comment: Why don't you just change it to 26.0.1?

Comment: tried your solution did not work

Answer (score 2):

I have tried replicating your case and found that

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

internally uses android appcompat version `25.2.0`

and hence to remove this error, just change your code from:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

TO

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'`

Also, if your `compileSdkVersion` is `26`, it will give warning so just change it to `25` and all your errors/warnings will be resolved(No red lines in `build.gradle`)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your targetSdkVersion is 26 means 
The appcompat library should be like below

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'